# Is it possible to update old xcode code to the latest xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, updating

So my developer developed my app in xcode 5 and i have the latest xcode version. When i tested the app on my version, a lot of features stopped working. My developer told me that it could be the different xcode versions between us. I was wondering if it is possible to fix this without changing the SDK or xcode version.

If it comes to me changing the xcode version, will i not be able to add apple's latest features to my app?

Also, when i add an SDK into the SDK folder, do i have to replace it with the current one or do i just leave both in there together?

BTW i don't know anything about programming, so i only speak noobish.

Thanks!

Comment: ...or it could be caused by deprecated or new APIs, technologies, maybe. as quick painkiller you can use older SDKs for compiling your project, but the recommended solution for long term is you need to keep your app up-to-dated for the latest technologies; otherwise your app is getting 'older' and at some point it 'dies' and you will need to invest more money to develop another app (from ground again) which conforms the latest technologies to run them properly on the latest platforms and devices.

Answer (score 1):

When parts of an application stop working after the version of Xcode is updated, the reason is almost always a change in the SDK since newer versions Xcode contain newer versions of the SDK. Additionally, stuff from older SDKs often gets deprecated and is eventually removed.

However, you should be aware that Xcode 5 is very dated nowadays and should not (and cannot) be used for developing applications for iOS 8. As a rule, when a new version of Xcode comes out, all existing code should be updated to the current version of the SDK and developers should upgrade to the latest version because it prevents issues like the ones you are describing.

Comment: Well, since you aren't a programmer you're going to need somebody with the right skills to go through your code base and make the necessary changes. Unfortunately, there really isn't another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the code as per the latest iOS version. All the deprecated methods need to be replaced with the new ones. Also the codes that once worked with previous versions of iOS may be or may not be working with the latest version of iOS i.e iOS 8. So an upgrade to the code will be required.